# Extending a component with additional properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, components

So I'm thinking about creating a simple component that I would be using on various different projects. The component provides a class (let's say, a car), that I use on many projects. The component also has things such as basic views for listing the various cars and persists its own data into a database via Entity Framework.

Now my question is, how do I extend this car component between projects? Most cars in the different projects have very similar properties, but they all have some extra ones. So how do I add this extra functionality (or just properties) to the component in a way that allows me to just update the .dll containing the component should I later on improve the base component? And how do I make the component "aware" of the extra columns in its db?

So far I've been considering two different alternatives, but don't like either. First would be to just take the latest version of the component, add the stuff that the current project needs and use that. But this obviously gets cumbersome if I want to update the base component. The second alternative I thought about would be that the main component has a link to an "extension" table that could then be defined further in the customizing project. Or something along those lines.

As you can probably tell, I've quite new to all this. So any and all tips are much appreciated!

Comment: That's what inheritance is for. Put the class in a separate assembly common to all projects and inherit from this class in other projects, adding new properties as needed.

Comment: But how does inheritance affect the link to the entity framework -model? Is there a way to have the EF model automatically update with the new properties introduced in the inherited class?

Comment: What do you mean with: And how do I make the component "aware" of the extra columns in its db?

Comment: You map your base class, and then you separately map additional properties from the derived classes. [For example, check this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: I mean that when I create the base component, I also create an EF model for it so that I can persist the object together with all of its properties to a database. Now, if I inherit a new class from the bas component and add a new property, lets say SubwooferType, which is not present in the main component because not all the cars have subwoofers. But all the cars of the inherited class do have them. So how do I now persist this new property together with the whole object?

Comment: Thanks Groo, that link provides a complete answer! Too bad you answered it as a comment though, cant select it as the answer -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by EF model you mean EDMX file then the answer is most probably: not directly possible. You can derive new component from existing one in another project / solution but you cannot extend EDMX = you must create new EDMX for the new component model in every project adding its customizations. EDMX is mapping and if you changed class or database you must define new mapping and because EDMX is XML file it cannot be inherited in the same simple way as you did it with a class (there is actually only one way how to reuse existing EDMX but it is very limited and very hard to use because it is not supported by designer in Visual Studio).

In case of code first you can define `EntityTypeConfiguration` for base component and inherit it in the new project to add your new properties. But again you will need some customization because your model builder in the new project will have to load correct (new) mapping configuration class instead of the old one used in original project.

In case of code first you can also use "default" mapping conventions which would make it work without any changes in mapping if you follow correct naming patterns (properties and classes in code must have same names as columns and tables in the database).

Another additional problem is with `ObjectSet` / `DbSet`. If your base context uses something like:

```
public ObjectSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

and you want to have only derived classes in your new project you should modify the context as well otherwise you will work with mapped inheritance which would only complicate everything.

Answer (score 0):

May be I missunderstood something, but you can have, for example:

```
//Component.DLL
public class Component 
{
   //basic functionality
}

//CarComponentDLL
public class CarComponent : Component 
{
  //extend component for cars 
}

//HorseComponentDLL
public class HorseComponent : Component
{
  //extend component for horses
}
```

now, different projects use different extensions, like `CarComponent` or `HorseComponent` like this

```
Component  mycompo = new HorseComponent ();
```

here I use extended for horses version of my component.  So *I'm aware* what kind of horse related filds needs horse in order to be able to access DB.

Now, when you're goona release new version of `Component`, just give them ComponentDLL, considering that changes made by you were made with back compatibility concept in mind, you will not break anything and client projects will continue to use their extended versions with your fixes.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not exactly what I was looking for, the main problem was the persistance to a database. I guess I just explained my situation a bit poorly.

Comment: @bobblez: weel, Component has a persistance acess to DB? Yes. CarComponent has persistance access to DB of Component + it's own fields. The same for HorseComponent.